# Why is my django model not saved?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this seemingly simple test case in a Django app, which fails:

```
def test_matches(self):
    # setup code...

    matches = tournament.match_set.order_by('match_id')

    matches[0].winner = 'a'
    matches[0].save()
    self.assertEqual(matches[0].winner, 'a')
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `matches` is not simply a list, but a `QuerySet`: indexing and slicing a `QuerySet` accesses the database, so each `matches[0]` returns a fresh match. `matches[0].save()` therefore saves an unmodified object.

As @Wtower notes, the relevant doc is found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

The way this should be written is this:

```
    m = matches[0]
    m.winner = 'a'
    m.save()
    self.assertEqual(matches[0].winner, 'a')
```

alternately, force evaluation of the `QuerySet` if that's what you want:

```
    matches = list(tournament.match_set.order_by('match_id'))
```

or better, if you can identify the match in the database:

```
    matches.filter(match_id=0).update(winner=0)
```

This way is way shorter, does the update in place without loading data into python and thus eliminates a possible race condition. However, filtering for `match_id` is (generally) not the same as indexing into the `QuerySet`. (a sliced `QuerySet` like `matches[0:1]` can't be updated)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated